# How are views/day calculated in Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, views

[Not programming related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) has 3,366 views a day. What's exactly a "view"?

- Are only unique visitors counted, like in question/profile views?
- Are search engines counted?
- Is it just pages served? That is, if I press <kbd>F5</kbd> all day will the number go considerably up?
- Is it something like the sum of question views + the sum of profile views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a sum of all unique IP address question views, so it is quite strict. Actual traditional sloppily counted pageviews would be about three times that, based on comparing the Google Analytics with that number.

Comment: So basically it's the number of questions that have been read; maybe a little clarification with a tooltip or something would be beneficial. Otherwise it seems like it's the "sloppily counted pageviews"; that's what I thought, but I realized it was quite low, so I asked.