# How is views/day calculated?

Tags: discussion, support, statistics, site-visits

On various Stack Exchange sites we see a side bar that tells us what the usage is.  One of the metrics is `views/day`  Jeff gives some description of it's calculation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63460/how-are-views-day-calculated-in-area51), but what I want to know is

> Is it an average?  If so, over what period of time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the time being `views/day` is coming straight from the [API](https://stackapps.com/).

<del>[`views_per_day`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats?help) there is the sum of all views (as determined by unique IP visits within a reasonable interval) on all questions (including deleted, closed, migrated, etc.) over the number of days the site has existed (as determined by the creation date of the oldest question).</del>

This formula has been tweaked in the face of site closure (Gadgets) and the fact that now that we have a bunch of sites, we're going to have a bunch of weird dates on questions due to migrations.

Now, a site's `views_per_day` is calculated as follows:

- V<sub>n</sub> = sum of view counts of all questions created after the site (regardless of where they were created originally)
- F(q) = (q's view count) * (number of days the site has existed) / (number of days q has existed)
- V<sub>u</sub> = sum of F(q) for all questions created before the site
- views_per_day = (V<sub>n</sub> + V<sub>u</sub>) / (number of days the site has existed)

This isn't perfect, but we don't track individual view events (we'd probably need a dedicated DB server for that on SO, just incrementing is already kind of painful without some tricks) so I think its OK given the data.

The whole scheme has some nice properties:

- migrated questions are reflected in the `views_per_day`, just ignoring them seems very wrong
- new sites don't get huge view boosts from being seeded with SE 1.0 sites
- questions that were asked on *another* site while the destination site existed, and then migrated, are counted immediately (as if they were asked on the correct site to begin with)
- newer questions have a larger impact than older ones

  - so a hot new question asked a day before the site was created would be reflected almost immediately, while an old one will be counted *eventually*
- all migrated questions are "eased in," so `views_per_day` doesn't jump sporadically

Though, obviously, `views_per_day` should still be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: Does it consider migrated questions to enstabilish the creation time?

Comment: @Kop - yes.  Excluding them makes something inaccurate (either the total question views or the time period for those views), so I took the easy way out and left them in.  This has a small effect on SE 2.0 sites, since the migration paths are quite limited.  With gadgets closure (and subsequent question "salvage") this may be changed if really neurotic numbers start showing up... but its not a high priority.  For the trilogy sites, they're both too big and too old for migrated questions to have much impact.

Comment: Won't just having a site.CreationDate column be easier? :S It can be set manually for old sites, and automatically from now on..

Comment: @Kop - we have a notion of site creation date, but if we use it then we're dividing question view count totals by a smaller period than they were "earned" in.  On the other hand, if we exclude migrated questions altogether, `views_per_day` won't reflect the popularity of a sites current content (regardless of where it came from originally).  There isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: ohh, I understand the problem now.. Thanks for explaining =)

Comment: @Kevin Montrose: Thanks. This explains why Apple.SE's views/day just halved.

Answer (score 6):

As an update to this post - we now pull visits / day directly from google analytics for the SE 2.0 sites.  This number will more closely match the number presented at stackexchange.com/sites.

> Visits = sessions.  A session is a
>   defined period of activity by a
>   visitor.  The standard criteria for a
>   session in Google Analytics is
>   activity without a break of more than
>   30 minutes OR closing the browser. 
>   So, if someone comes to your site,
>   looks at two pages, goes to lunch and
>   leaves their browser open, comes back
>   an hour later  and resumes browsing, a
>   second session would be started.  If a
>   user viewed two pages on your site,
>   closed their browser, and came back 5
>   minutes later, they would create a new
>   session.