# How are the "questions per day" calculated?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

Referring to here: https://stackexchange.com/sites#users

[image]

Hovering over the `questions/day` I see `per day on average over the last 2 weeks`.

But where/how is this actually calculated (formula, etc.)?  I'm hoping for the details similar to how Kevin answered here: [How is views/day calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64863/how-is-views-day-calculated)

Comment: Not even close to an answer @Servy.  Not even a decent comment.  Does it include migrated from questions?  Migrated to questions?  There's more to it than you state otherwise the data.stackexchange.com site would easily retrieve it with posttypeid=1.

Comment: @Servy `select count(*) / 14 from Posts where CreationDate >= dateadd(day, -13, datediff(day, 0, getdate())) and PostTypeId=1` returns `4531`

Comment: @Stijn The data explorer doesn't have very up to date results.  Just run `select Max(CreationDate) from Posts where  PostTypeId=1`  [I got](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/142106) `2013-10-06 06:54:37`  When you're missing several days worth of data obviously it won't match.

Comment: @Servy: I'm guessing that a query corrected to take account the date that the data was dumped also doesn't give a reasonable answer - I'm sure you'd have take great pleasure in showing us had it done so ;)

Comment: @Iain Well, you'd have to actually do that.  How do you know that it *won't* match?

Comment: @Servy: No, I couldn't do it I don't have the skills but if I did and I'd gone to the trouble of doing what you did I'd definitely have run the query and posted the result unless ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What [the Stats Say](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users)

[image: Questions per Day]

We want to find a number matching 7,176 questions per day over the past two weeks.

## Simple Search

I searched for all questions created in the past two weeks (October 1st through October 14th) with [this simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2013-10-1..2013-10-14).

This returns 100,489 questions.

Dividing by 14 to get the daily answer, we get 7,177.786/day, which is 2/day above our target.

If we extend the search [to October 15th](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2013-10-1..2013-10-15) we get 100,988 posts.

## Conjecture

The calculation is not for full days, but for hours. Rather than searching by day, it is likely searching for posts made over the past 336 hours.

Since the standard search does not include deleted posts, chances are that deleted posts are excluded.

I believe Migrated posts are also excluded as well.

Comment: Thanks jmac.  http://meta.serverfault.com/a/5887/7861 is an "official" answer btw (albeit still a little fuzzy, but ok).  It doesn't count deleted but does count closed.  I like how you explained how you searched though, since numerous attempts on the data.stackexchange.com didn't work.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't official or intended to be (note the 'conjecture' titling), but it was close. I'm glad it was of some use.