# Is visits/day calculated differently on the Area 51 view than on the Stack Exchange site list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, traffic

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111882/how-can-we-have-a-31-day-old-site-with-14k-views-but-only-138-visits-day) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63460/how-are-views-day-calculated-in-area-51), the visits/day metric on sites' Area 51 page is calculated as the *median* number of visits per day over the previous 14 days. At the moment, [the Area 51 page for the Mathematica site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica) is showing a figure of 718.

But on the [main StackExchange site's listing of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#mathematica), it's 717. That's also the number showing in the little box on the [front page of the site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

It's a trivial difference, but it got me wondering if there was some kind of rounding bug or inconsistent calculation methods going on. Are the calculations different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch – the code was slightly different. Area 51 rounded to the nearest integer, while Stack Exchange always rounded down. Stack Exchange has been updated to also round to the nearest integer, so the two numbers should match now.

Comment: Glad I could help! I am just surprised that rounding is necessary if the *median* is used, per [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111889/168088). Perhaps the answer should be updated?

Comment: @Verbeia When there is an even number of values, the median is the mean of the two middle values.

Comment: Oh duh, of course. I should know that - obviously too early in the morning here in Oz.